# How to change Jupyterlab sidebar position

Tags: jupyter-lab

After first use Jupyterlab sidebar was on the left.
Sometime it switched to the right. I want to undock it from right to left (or vice versa).
How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just right-click on the item you want to move to the other side and choose "Switch Sidebar Side".

[image: Switching sidebar side illustration]

Comment: Didn't think it is so easy!